# Sync call electron on nodejs

Tags: node.js, printing, synchronization, electron

Well i have an application that prints receipts using a spooler made from the company of the fiscal printer that i use to this.

This spooler prints using command lines that i send it on a file.

Once i send it and start to prints and the spooler release the thread, while continue printing. Once it finish this spooler generates a log file, with some data that i need to save on a database.

My problem is when i send the event for print and this start, but never read the file log on **production** while isn't compiled it works perfectly.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
ipcMain.on("syncPrinter", function (event, content) {
    var responsePrinter = {
        status: null,
        file_response: null
    };
    /* Send file with commands to print*/
    exec('wspooler.exe -p4 -l -f FILE.200', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        /* if fails on send file to print*/
        if (err !== null) {
            responsePrinter = {
                status: false,
                file_response: null
            };
            event.returnValue = responsePrinter;
        } else {
            var cont = 0;
            /* starts a interval to wait file log of printer*/
            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                /* Open general log of the spooler */
                var spoolerLog = path.join(__dirname, 'spooler.log');
                fs.readFile(spoolerLog, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function (err, data) {
                    if (!err) {
                        var splited = data.split("\n");
                        /* Control if the last message on the genera log end the printing properly*/
                        if ((
                                splited[splited.length - 1].substring(16, 33) === 'Fin de la operaci'
                                && splited[splited.length - 3].substring(16, 43) === 'Archivo FILE.200 finalizado'
                                ) || (
                                splited[splited.length - 2].substring(16, 33) === 'Fin de la operaci'
                                && splited[splited.length - 4].substring(16, 43) === 'Archivo FILE.200 finalizado'
                                )) {
                            /* IF THE PRINT SUCCESS THIS FILE MUST BE READ */
                            var filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'FILE.ans');
                            fs.readFile(filePath, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function (err, response) {
                                if (!err) {
                                    responsePrinter.status = true;
                                    responsePrinter.file_response = response;
                                    /* send it to the frontend*/
                                    event.returnValue = responsePrinter;
                                    clearInterval(interval);
                                } else {
                                    cont++;
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            cont++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        cont++;
                    }
                });
                /* Repeat 10 times to wait the file to save*/
                if (cont > 10) {
                    responsePrinter = {
                        status: false,
                        file_response: null,
                        count: cont
                    };
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    event.returnValue = responsePrinter;
                }
            }, 4000);
        }
    });
});
```